# Cookie is being sent as cookie But not Cookie in request header

Tags: cookies, https, http-headers

I am written on AWS Gateway. In that I have exposed one `/v1/login` API. The API invokes the `lambda`. When I hit this API in the response I have set the cookie.

```
'multiValueHeaders': {
  'Set-Cookie': [
    f'access_token={user_info["access_token"]}; Secure; SameSite=Strict',
    f'refresh_token={user_info["refresh_token"]}; Secure; SameSite=Strict'
  ]
}
```

After setting the cookie, When I hit another API request the cookie is being sent with the request.

From my laptop (edge/chrome browser) in request cookie is sent in a variable `cookie`,
But with different laptop (same edge/chrome browser version) with same login user in request cookie is in a variable `Cookie`?

Why this problem is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your server-side code to handle both "Set-Cookie" and "Cookie" headers in the request. You can also configure your clients to consistently send the same case for the header field name. For example, you can use a standard library or a third-party package to set the header field name in a consistent case for all requests.

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com'
headers = {'set-cookie': 'access_token=123456', 'cookie': 'session_id=abc123'}

// Create a case-insensitive dictionary to store the headers
ci_headers = requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict(headers)

// Access the headers using any case
print(ci_headers['Set-Cookie'])  # 'access_token=123456'
print(ci_headers['COOKIE'])  # 'session_id=abc123'

// Make a request with the headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=ci_headers)
```